# Drop down menu on android button to start multiple activities

Tags: java, android, button, android-activity, drop-down-menu

I want to create a button in my activity so that clicking the button shows drop down menu list and when an option is selected from drop down list a new activity start.
So Basically I want to start multiple activities on my button click in android app.  I have found this tutorial http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-spinner-drop-down-list-example/
but here i can just toast an item selected and if I try starting new intent instead of toast I get error. 
Kindly guide me plus if there is any better idea to do this let me know please.

Comment: Could you post the error you get, and the code? There's no reason you shouldn't be able to do what you want to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to modify the function that listens for clicks on the spinner, and start the desired activity depending on which item was clicked:

```
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {
    Activity activity = (Activity) parent.getContext();
    Intent myIntent = new Intent();
    if (pos == 0) {
        myIntent.setClassName(activity, MyActivity1.class);
    } else if (pos == 1) {
        myIntent.setClassName(activity, MyActivity2.class);
    }
    activity.startActivity(myIntent);
}
```

Comment: Bruce. Thanks this works great to start activity, but got another problem if you can guide me. When my app start it take sme on the first option activity automatically rather than wait for an item to be selected by me. If I press back button of mobile then it takes me to the main activity where I specified the spinner. so I dont know if it is spinner problem or it is the problem in selection item code.

Comment: I'm very glad to hear you solved it, but for the record I'd like to offer a solution to your previous comment. I would solve that by making the first selection something like "Select an activity" so when the spinner is set to that value, and the listener called, you can do nothing for (pos == 0). Then when the user selects one of the other items you can launch the corresponding activity. Anyway, glad to help!